# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'detailUrl') at Buynow.js:57:1

Tags: reactjs, mern

I'm working on cart page of my amazon clone project.whenevr user add product i want to displa that at this cart page.but I'm facing some issue. in buynow i'm trying to access data using e keyword. but its not giving me error.

**Buynow.js**

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
    import "./buynow.css"
    import { Divider } from '@mui/material';
    import Option from './Option';
    import Subtotal from './Subtotal';
    import Right from './Right';

    const Buynow = () => {

    const [cartdata,setCartdata] = useState("");
    // console.log(cartdata.carts)


    const getdatabuy = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("/cartdetails",{
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
       
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept" : "application/json"

    },
    credentials: "include"
    });

    const data = await res.json();
    
    if (res.status !== 201) {
    console.log("error");
    } else {
    setCartdata(data.carts);
    }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
    getdatabuy();
    }, []);


    return (
    <>

    {
    cartdata.length ? <div className='buynow_section'>
    <div className="buynow_container">
    <div className="left_buy">
    <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
    <p>Select all item</p>
    <span className='leftbuyprice'>Price</span>
    <Divider />
    {
    cartdata.map((e, k) => {
    return (
    <>
    <div className="item_containert" >
    <img src= {e.detailUrl} alt="cartt" />
    <div className="item_details">
    <h3>'Molife Sense 500 Smartwatch  (Black Strap, Freesize)' </h3>
    <h3>Smart Watch</h3>
    <h3 className="diffrentprice">₹4049.00</h3>
    <p className="unusuall">Usually dispatched in 8 days.</p>
    <p>Eligible for FREE Shipping</p>
    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/31/marketing/fba/fba-badge_18px-2x._CB485942108_.png" alt="logo" />
                         
    <Option />
    </div>
    <div className="item_price">₹4049.00</div>
    </div>
    </> 
    )
    })
    }
    <Divider />
    <Subtotal />
    </div>

    <div className="right_buy">
    <Right />
    </div>
    </div>
    </div> : " "
     }
    </>
    )

     };


     export default Buynow
```

**productdata.js**

````
    export const products = [
    { 
    id: 'product1',
    url: 
   'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/150/150/kapoo7k0/electric- 
    kettle/p/6/s/pigeon- favourite-original-imafs7xhj5uwgrh4.jpeg? 
    q=70', 
    detailUrl: 
    'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/kapoo7k0/electric- 
    kettle/p/6/s/pigeon-favourite-original-imafs7xhj5uwgrh4.jpeg?q=70',
    title: {
    shortTitle: 'Home & Kitchen',
    longTitle: 'Pigeon FAVOURITE Electric Kettle  (1.5 L, Silver, 
    Black)'
    }, 
    price: {
    mrp: 1195,
    cost: 625,
    discount: '47%'
    },
    description: 'This electric kettle from Pigeon will soon become a 
    travelers best friend, a  hostelite saviour and an answer to all 
    the midnight cravings. With this handy appliance, you can boil 
    water and use it to make instant noodles, packet soup, coffee and 
    green tea.',
    discount: 'Extra 10% Off', 
    tagline: 'Deal of the day' 
    },
    { 
    id: 'product2',
    url: 
    'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/kl6wx3k0/sandwich- 
    maker/8/r/d/sandwich-01-flipkart-smartbuy-original- 
    imagydds4zthxt8z.jpeg?q=70', 
    detailUrl: 
    'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/kl6wx3k0/sandwich- 
    maker/8/r/d/sandwich-01-flipkart-smartbuy-original- 
    imagydds4zthxt8z.jpeg?q=70',
    title: {
    shortTitle: 'Sandwich Makers',
    longTitle: 'Flipkart SmartBuy Sandwich 01 Grill  (Black)'
    },
    price: {
    mrp: 1499,
    cost: 899,
    discount: '40%'
    },
    description: 'This non-stick sandwich toaster .easy to use and very 
    handy. Directly hold over flame to make tasty toasts and toasted 
    sandwiches. Specially designed by keeping your needs in mind, the 
    sandwich maker makes whatever youre doing simpler, smarter and 
    better',
    discount: 'From 99+5% Off', 
    tagline: 'Pestige, Nova & more' 
    },
    { 
    id: 'product3',
    url: 
    'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/150/150/kohigsw0/resistance- 
    tube/c/s/e/new-adjustable-single-resistance-tube-multicolor-na- 
    ajro-deal-original-imag2xg88mhmwxz5.jpeg?q=70', 
    detailUrl: 
    'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/kohigsw0/resistance- 
    tube/c/s/e/new-adjustable-single-resistance-tube-multicolor-na- 
    ajro-deal-original-imag2xg88mhmwxz5.jpeg?q=70', 
    title: {
    shortTitle: 'Fitness Gear',
    longTitle: 'AJRO DEAL New Adjustable Single Resistance Tube 
    (Multicolor) Resistance Tube  (Multicolor)'
    }, 
    price: {
    mrp: 499,
    cost: 166,
    discount: '66%'
    },
    description: 'This unique product can tone your back muscles, 
    reduce belly fat, improve blood circulation and also improves your 
    body posture. It increases the stamina, energy and vitality of the 
    body. The elastic resistance of the rubber training rope can be 
    used to train and exercise in whichever way you want, according to 
    your physical needs.',
    discount: 'Upto 70% Off', 
    tagline: 'Deal of the Day' 
    },
    ]```


I want different product that are selected by user on cart page
````

Comment: the problem seems to be `cartdata.map((e, k) => { ... <img src= {e.detailUrl} alt="cartt" /> ... }`. So what is `cartdata` and how do you pouplate it. Seems that there is at least one `null` element in `cartdata`

Comment: but i tried it before by just typing image address it'giving me correct output.but all products showing me same image. and when i use that e its giving me this error

Comment: Can you `console.log(cartData)`? To see what's it returns?

Comment: yes.its showing me that particular items detail.like img url,title and all.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code :

```
  const [cartdata, setCartdata] = useState([]);

  const getCartItems = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/cartdetails", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        credentials: "include"
      });

      if (res.ok) {
        const data = await res.json();
        setCartdata(data.carts || []); // Assuming the cart items are in data.carts
      } else {
        console.log("Error fetching cart items");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching cart items:", error);
    }
  };
```

also  :

```
{cartdata.map((item) => (
                <div className="item_container" key={item.id}>
                  <img src={item.detailUrl} alt={item.title.longTitle} />
                  <div className="item_details">
                    <h3>{item.title.longTitle}</h3>
                    {/* Other details */}
                    <Option />
                  </div>
                  <div className="item_price">{/* Display item price */}</div>
                </div>
              ))}
              <Divider />
              <Subtotal />
            </div>
            <div className="right_buy">
              <Right />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>No items</p>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Buynow;
```